# An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext on swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm authorizing OAuth token in swagger. It's not working in swagger but it is working on postman

This is my error:

```
{
  "error": "unauthorized",
  "error_description": "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"
}
```

these dependency versions I'm using:

```
Spring-boot parent version-2.2.1, 
the swagger-UI version is 2.8.0, 
swagger spring fox version is 2.8.0
```

I'm stuck in this problem for the past 2 days. How could I solve it?

Comment: Hello, would be nice if you share your code with us, thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already rectified that issue

Comment: I want one favor from you, can you help me?. It's related to cron expression for quartz

Answer (score -1):

When you authorize the token in swagger add this line to the authorized textbox: put **bearer** before the token